# For loop through json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, for-loop

I've this server produced JSON, which I use for adding a description, price, time and date to a page using jQuery.

```
[{
    "palvelu_id": "1",
    "palvelu_nimi": "Meikkikoulutus",
    "palvelu_kuvaus": "Description",
    "palvelu_hinta": "10"
}, {
    "aika_id": "1",
    "aika_kello": "14.00",
    "aika_paivamaara": "28.10.2013",
    "aika_paikkoja": "5",
    "aika_palvelu": "1"
}, {
    "aika_id": "2",
    "aika_kello": "12.00",
    "aika_paivamaara": "12.10.2013",
    "aika_paikkoja": "1",
    "aika_palvelu": "1"
}]
```

So I'm adding content to div `#ajanvarausInfo`, which works fine. But, I'm also trying to add options to a select field, which isn't quite working as I only get one `<option></option>`.

I'm new to `for` loops, and I'm not quite sure how they work.

```
var json = $.parseJSON(thejson);
    $("#ajanvarausInfo").html(json[0].palvelu_kuvaus+"<br>Osallistuminen maksaa "+json[0].palvelu_hinta+ "&euro;.");

for(var i = 0; i < json.length;i++){
    $("#asiakasAika").html('<option value="'+json[1].aika_id+'">'+json[1].aika_kello+' '+json[1].aika_paivamaara+'</option');
}
```

Comment: well, instead of `[1]`, you want `[i]`...

Comment: @KevinB Did that, but I still get only one option on my select.

Comment: Also, as your you are not putting the first json object into the options element, start your for loop with 1, instead of 0 and add 1 to the length `for(var i = 1; i < (json.length+1);i++)`. Also, as someone suggested, use .append() instead of .html()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `.html()`, use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Your JSON is also incorrect. If you want to have multiple items, you need to wrap them in another JSON element, then loop through that:

```
[{
    "palvelu_id":"1",
    "palvelu_nimi":"Meikkikoulutus",
    "palvelu_kuvaus":"Description",
    "palvelu_hinta":"10"
}, 
{
    "items": {
                "aika_id":"1",
                "aika_kello":"14.00",
                "aika_paivamaara":"28.10.2013",
                "aika_paikkoja":"5",
                "aika_palvelu":"1"
             },
             {
                "aika_id":"2",
                "aika_kello":"12.00",
                "aika_paivamaara":"12.10.2013",
                "aika_paikkoja":"1",
                "aika_palvelu":"1"
             }
}]
```

Then loop like this:

```
 $.each(data.items, function () { alert(this.aika_id) });
```

Comment: Of course! That's the reason why I only have 1 option. But as the json is generated by php, and then retrieved by **one** ajax request, how could I have to json elements and use both of them?

Comment: just loop through the dynamic data and add them to the items with your PHP. you can have base items then collections of multiple items to loop through if you use the syntax i provided.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but how would I actually do that? As the data comes from database, and I merge two arrays and convert them into JSON there.

Comment: you could build a an array with base items then in one of the array nodes put the results of your db query, then json_encode the whole thing and echo it. i'm not a php expert but this seems simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < json.length;i++){
    $("#asiakasAika").append('<option value="'+json[i].aika_id+'">'+json[i].aika_kello+' '+json[i].aika_paivamaara+'</option>');
}
```

Change 1 to i

Comment: Each loop overwrites the previous values. And you ignored the bad ending tag. And the fact that the JSON is rather oddly structured (option values start from index 1).

Comment: You are getting one `<option>` becuse you do not append the new `<option>`. You are instead replacing all html for the element.
Try `$("#asiakasAika").append` instead. Edited the example

Comment: @Juhana Thanks, didn't even spot that I've bad ending on option.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery built in each functionality

```
var id = $('#asiakasAika');
$.each(json, function(key, value){
  id.append('<option value="'+value.aika_id+'">'+value.aika_kello+' '+value.aika_paivamaara+'</option>');
});
```

Comment: My bad I thought it was faster... but it does hold scope (and looks way cleaner!)

Comment: Well it's not that much faster, but will do this time. I did the mistake and learn jQuery before learning regular js at all, might as well learn to use it ;)